# Google OAuth2.0 Client Whitelist not working

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-api

I have set up a client application in google's oauth2.0 console to authenticate my website with google calendar. I am getting the following error:

```
error:
"idpiframe_initialization_failed"
details:
"Not a valid origin for the client: http://www.heaolumassage.com has not been whitelisted for client ID 245143078821-1reoo9h3ch0334pi6sddp52cnnotl316.apps.googleusercontent.com. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and whitelist this origin for your project's client ID."
```

However, I have the origin set in the configuration for the client id:

```
Authorized JavaScript origins
For use with requests from a browser. This is the origin URI of the client 
application. It can't contain a wildcard (http://*.example.com) or a path 
(http://example.com/subdir). If you're using a nonstandard port, you must 
include it in the origin URI.

http://www.heaolumassage.com 
http://heaolumassage.com
```

I am also able to successfully authenticate with the same code from a server on my local machine. Are there any other places where the origin must be specified?

Comment: Make sure that you use a correct client Id. Make sure you don't have any spaces in the console entries. It sometimes takes a few minutes as well for the Console to propagate your settings.